# Edit code to run on UI thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface

I am getting a wrong thread error, so I am thinking I need to be running invalidate from the UI thread. Usually I have something like:

```
public void run() {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
}});
```

But I need to name this runnable to reference it from a method. How do i incorporate runOnUiThread into this?

```
Handler viewHandler = new Handler();
Runnable updateView = new Runnable() {
@Override

public void run() {

    mEmulatorView.invalidate();

    if (statusBool == true) {
        for (int i = 1; i < dataReceived.length() - 1; i++) {

            if (dataReceived.charAt(i) == '>') {

                Log.d(TAG, "found >");
                deviceStatus = 0;
            }
            if (dataReceived.charAt(i) == '#'
                    && dataReceived.charAt(i - 1) != ')') {

                Log.d(TAG, "found #");
                deviceStatus = 1;
            }
            if ((i + 1) <= (dataReceived.length())
                    && dataReceived.charAt(i) == ')'
                    && dataReceived.charAt(i + 1) == '#') {

                Log.d(TAG, "found config )#");
                deviceStatus = 2;
            }

        }
        statusBool = false;
        viewHandler.postDelayed(updateView, 1000);

    }
}
};
```

calling it:

```
public void onDataReceived(int id, byte[] data) {

        dataReceived = new String(data);
        ((MyBAIsWrapper) bis).renew(data);
        mSession.write(dataReceived);
        viewHandler.post(updateView);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're calling it wrong thread? If you post it to `viewHandler` and `viewhandler` was created on ui thread then it shouldn't throw such error.

Comment: Can you post error message here?

Comment: here is the error: http://i.imgur.com/s4mTt.png

Comment: I have a thread about it but I really don't know what to do :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384452/android-ui-thread-issue

Comment: Did you try `runOnUiThread(updateView)` instead of `viewhandler.post(updateView)`?

Comment: I tried that and got the same error. I commented out the line I use to write to the terminal mSession.write(dataReceived); and I dont get the error. But of course nothing is then written to the screen

Comment: Aaaah. So `updateView` doesn't cause any problems.  Then you should wrap all code inside `onDataReceived` method to `Runnable` and send it to UI thread.

Comment: What I did to fix it was put the write line in a UI thread itself, even though i thought it already was! I'll post the fixed code below. thanks.

Comment: if you write an answer I'll accept it, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to name it. If you want to post itself you can just use `this` keyword:

```
viewHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
```

**UPDATE**

Wrong thread error caused by `mSession.write(dataReceived);`. `updateView` doesn't cause any problems. Try to wrap `mSession.write` to runnable and call it on ui thread.

Comment: Thanks I will try that now, is it not possible to do both however?

Answer (score 1):

Got it working, I just had to run that write line in a UI thread, even though I thought it was?!

```
public void onDataReceived(int id, byte[] data) {

        dataReceived = new String(data);
        ((MyBAIsWrapper) bis).renew(data);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() { 
                mSession.write(dataReceived);       
            }});

        viewHandler.post(updateView);
    }
```